# Cant Figure out a good way to query a datatable in vb.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net

So I'm making an application that gets all the events for a month out of a mysql DB and adds them to a calendar. I've got the events in a data table atm "dbTable"

The events are ascending by date

```
"SELECT * FROM table_events WHERE date BETWEEN '" & startDate & "' AND '" & endDate & "' ORDER BY date ASC"
```

Now I need to query each day one at a time to check for up to 6 events per date, any suggestions? Im not even sure on how to query the data table let alone do it for up to 31 days and make it somewhat efficient.

Comment: wouldn't it be far more efficient to just add `and eventID in (1,2,3,4,5,6)`? running a per-day query to look for stuff is incredibly inefficient, when you could just query for the daterange AND the events you're interested for.

Comment: Every Event is needed for the calendar, and events could be added  out of order thats why date is the selected method. I only connect to the Database once for the information as it gets the whole month in one query, im just not sure on how to query the data table to retrieve the information in the way i would if i was to query it from the mysql DB day by day. I had the application set up with a loop that checked all the days of the month 1 by 1 but it connected to the DB each time, i would like to only query the DB once and query the data table for daily results.

Comment: but the event would say what day(s) it's on, so `order by eventdate` or whatever...

Comment: ticks are not an all purpose variable delimiter.  if the date field (still a bad name) is a Date type, the ticks convert the data - which also should be a `DateTime` type - to string.

Comment: so my question is then, how do i query the data table as i would the mysqltable? and i'll change it from date to eventDate to make it less redundant. the type in the mysqlDB is Date

Comment: You will have to loop thru your datatable, the SQL part is correct.

Comment: Are you using a calendar control? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.monthcalendar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: I'm using a calendar called calendar.net it's a calendar control that allows for events to be added by day , I have the callendar working perfectly by looping day by day via mysql , open conn check date1 count events write events , close conn then restarts with day it does this for each month , I'm hoping by getting the whole month from the db at once and just reading the stable in the same manner it will be quicker to open

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so after trying and reading i've figured it out. Thanks to all of you for your input.

```
            Dim count As Integer
            Dim expression As String
            Dim foundRows() As DataRow
            count = 0

            expression = "date = '" & numericYear & "-" & doubleMonth & "-01'"


            foundRows = dbTable.Select(expression)
            For count = 0 To foundRows.Length - 1
                'count = count + "1"
                MessageBox.Show(dbTable.Rows(count).Item(5).ToString())

            Next count
```

Where in this example numericYear = 2015 and doubleMonth = 06